# How to debug: Unable to connect to database from inside a Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, amazon-ec2, dokku

I'm a relative noob w.r.t. many of the moving parts on the system that I'm working on, and so please pardon me for a lack of understanding in places. My question here is more about asking for debugging strategies rather than asking for a solution to the problem, as I am drawing a blank at the moment.

## Current Setup

I'm running a Docker container on an EC2 instance. All instances run in my company VPC. I need to connect to a Postgres database that lives on a workstation on-premise. The Docker container is spun-up and spun-down automatically using [Dokku](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku), an open source Heroku-alternative that I finally figured out how to get setup on EC2.

Some variables I will be using in the post:

- `DBSERVER`: The address of the workstation that is hosting our database.
- `DOKKUSERVER`: The address of the Dokku EC2 instance.
- `APPCONTAINER`: The Docker container, spun up by Dokku, that houses my app.
- `APPNAME`: The application name on Dokku

## What works

When I enter into the `APPCONTAINER` with `dokku enter APPNAME`, I can ping `DBSERVER` and get back a response:

```
(environment_name) [root@APPCONTAINER project]# ping DBSERVER
PING DBSERVER (DB_SERVER_IP) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from DBSERVER (DB_SERVER_IP): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=95.9 ms
64 bytes from DBSERVER (DB_SERVER_IP): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=96.2 ms
64 bytes from DBSERVER (DB_SERVER_IP): icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=95.7 ms
```

## What doesn't work

However, when I try to connect using `pgcli`, I find I cannot connect:

```
(environment_name) [root@APPCONTAINER project]# pgcli -h $DB_SERVER -p $DB_PORT -U $DB_USER -d $DB_NAME
could not send SSL negotiation packet: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Additionally, from my Python app, in which we use both `psycopg2` and `sqlalchemy` (in different parts of the codebase), I find we cannot connect to the database. On the other hand, connection from my local machine (i.e. my laptop, or another workstation that is on-premise) works without issue.

My main problem here is that the Python app requires a connection to the database via `psycopg2` and `sqlalchemy`, but that isn't working.

## Current hypotheses

To recap, I am drawing a blank here on how to debug, and so I'm asking for debugging strategies (i.e. what should I look at) with hopefully some pointers to docs on how to debug. (Exact commands - I am happy to look them up, if pointed to the docs pages.) Things I have thought of, but am not sure how to look at, are:

- Debugging "the connection" (still a nebulous term in my head) between the Docker container on EC2 and the on-premise workstation?

Things I have done already are:

- checking to ensure that environment variables are set correctly
- ensuring that ports are set correctly for the app to work
- entering into the Docker container that Dokku is running and checking that the source code is correct.

Are there other debugging strategies that I might have missed? I would love to be enlightened on them please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was answered [on twitter](https://twitter.com/ericmjl/status/1167971594301394949), but the problem was the user had not created the correct security group rules on their AWS account to allow traffic from the server to the database.